# Using For loop in latex to input multiple files in different directories

Tags: programming, foreach

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcounter{question}
\newcounter{answer}
\setcounter{question}{0}    
\setcounter{answer}{0}
\newcommand\Que[1]{
\stepcounter{question}}
\newcommand\Ans[2][]{
\stepcounter{answer}}
\newcommand\MAX{10}
\begin{document} 
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\MAX} {%
        \edef\File{ques\i}%     The % here are necessary to eliminate any
        \edef\FileName{ans\i}%     The % here are necessary to eliminate any
        \IfFileExists{\FileName}{%  spurious spaces that may get inserted
            \input{\File}%       at these points
            \input{\FileName}%       at these points
        }
    }
\end{document}
```

This is code of my main latex file and I have two other directories named Question and Answer. There are about six question `.tex` files in Question directory named `ques1`, `ques2` ... and same number of `.tex` files in Answer directory named `ans1`,`ans2`,... and I want to specify directory in above for loop so that it automatically picks up files from these above mentioned folders so that I don't have to keep them in a single folder.
Also is there a way that I can omit supplying the values of i and rather supply some other condition that can read all `.tex` files in a folder.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete minimal document rather than just a fragment of code. How is `\foreach` defined, for example? It is not standard LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks!! There are multiple files. For \foreach , I used a package called pgffor in usepackage document and hope rest is understandable.

Comment: Please provide it as a complete minimal example. That is, start your example `\documentclass{}...` and keep going until `\end{document}`. Any required packages should be included so that people can copy-paste-compile the code.

Comment: You don't say what the problem is. You've already got a loop. I don't think you can avoid explicitly iterating unless you execute external commands directly. Maybe you can, but I wouldn't think so. That would need shell escape etc. (Unless you use LuaTeX where it is unsafe by default as far as I can tell.)

Comment: What other condition do you want to use?

Comment: @cfr, Thanks for your reply. Hope you see better posts by me in future. I have just modified it so that it's working can be checked and yes, this for loop does satisfy my purpose. I just wanted to know if one could include directory name in \input in for loop.

Comment: @Jon, the other condition was that can I use *.tex in the condition part of for loop

Comment: Why can't you simply build on what you have and add `\edef\ADir{ans\i} \edef\QDir{ques\i}` and `\IfFileExists{\ADir/\FileName}{ \input{\QDir/\File} \input{\ADir/\FileName}`?

Comment: I tried this but it gives an unrecognized control sequence error. But Thank you and yes, now my purpose is solved.